# Duplicate class error when trying to build

Tags: android, gradle, butterknife

I use butterKnife 5.1.0 with gradle. When i try to build the project gradle throws the following exception.

```
error: duplicate class: in.test.android.activity.AboutUsScreen$$ViewInjector
```

I am using butterknife jar file, and I have added these 3 lines in progaurd

```
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewInjector { *; }
-keepnames class * { @butterknife.InjectView *;}
```

Am i missing something here.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @WindsurferOak.. no I couldn't.. Got rid of butterknife...:-)

Answer (score 1):

If you import form ADT,and your ADT using Dagger it will be happen.

so just delete all import duplicate file in you workspace. it is work for me.